# Restoring using recovery partition without losing software

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, data-recovery, downgrade

I was using Windows 7, later on I moved to Windows 8. I installed some applications after that. I want to revert back to Windows 7. I have a recovery disk in my laptop, but I do not want to lose any software I have installed after upgrading to Windows 8.

Is it possible?

Comment: In short... no. To get back to Win 7 you will have to nuke & pave, or restore to a backup from that time. Laptop recovery volumes usually restore to a known default state, as it was when new.

Comment: The recovery disk you have doesn't provide the capability you seek

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft did not provide a standard method for downgrade.
There is no true downgrade - you will be doing a completely clean install of Windows 7. You will lose everything - files, applications, device drivers. Everything.

You would be better off staying with Windows 8, but installing third-party
applications that will approximate the way you worked with Windows 7.

An example is [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) that will give you back a Start menu
similar to that of Windows 7 (or even better).